# Colocando sub-itens no menu em CSS3

Tags: css3

Estou criando um menu drop'n down em CSS3, mas não estou conseguindo estilizar o terceiro nível.

O CSS tá assim:

```
*{margin: 0; padding:0;}
.menu{width: 100%; height: 50px; background-color:#222; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
.menu ul{list-style:none; position:relative;}
.menu ul li{width: 150px; float:left;}
.menu a{padding: 15px; display:block; text-decoration:none; text-align:center; background-color:#222; color:#fff;}
.menu ul ul{position: absolute; visibility:hidden;}
.menu ul li:hover ul{visibility: visible;}
.menu ul ul li:hover ul{visibility: visible;}
.menu a:hover{background-color:#f4f4f4; color:#555;}
.menu ul ul li{float: none; border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;}
.menu ul ul li a{background-color: #999;}
label[for="bt_menu"]{padding: 5px; background-color: #222; color: #FFFFFF; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:30px; cursor: pointer; width: 50px; height:50px;}
```

O HTML está assim:

```
<nav class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Ve&iacute;culos</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Novos</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Seminovos</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">F&amp;I</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Peças</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Balc&atilde;o</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Oficina</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Mec&acirc;nica</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Funilaria</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Acessórios</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Até o Segundo nível vai de boa, mas acho que eu não soube configurar o terceiro nível    :/

O resultado do código no navegador ficou assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sendo que o desejável seria que ficasse assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acho que você estava quase lá.

O problema é que não está sabendo distinguir os níveis dos elementos.

Quando você segue dois seletores usando espaço, o CSS seleciona todos os subelementos em quaisquer níveis.

```
a b {} /* qualquer b em qualquer nível dentro de a */
```

O que eu acho que você gostaria de usar é o operador `>`, que significa: o filho imediato, ao invés de qualquer um em qualquer subnível.

```
a > b {} /* seleciona "b" que é filho imediato de "a"
```

Note as linhas que eu comentei do seu CSS, com as alterações necessárias (fiz um resumo das alterações, com explicações, logo abaixo do trecho de código abaixo):

```css
*{margin: 0; padding:0;}
.menu{width: 100%; height: 50px; background-color:#222; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
.menu ul{list-style:none; position:relative;}
.menu ul li{width: 150px; float:left;}
.menu a{padding: 15px; display:block; text-decoration:none; text-align:center; background-color:#222; color:#fff;}
.menu ul ul{position: absolute; visibility:hidden;}

/*.menu ul li:hover ul{visibility: visible;}*/
.menu ul li:hover > ul{visibility: visible;}

/*.menu ul ul li:hover ul{visibility: visible;}*/

.menu a:hover{background-color:#f4f4f4; color:#555;}
.menu ul ul li{float: none; border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;}
.menu ul ul li > a{background-color: #999;}
label[for="bt_menu"]{padding: 5px; background-color: #222; color: #FFFFFF; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:30px; cursor: pointer; width: 50px; height:50px;}

/* adicionados */
.menu ul li ul li { white-space: nowrap; }
.menu ul li ul li > a { display: inline-block; width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box; }
.menu ul li ul li > ul { display: inline-block; }
```

```html
<nav class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Ve&iacute;culos</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Novos</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Seminovos</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">F&amp;I</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Peças</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Balc&atilde;o</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Oficina</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Mec&acirc;nica</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Funilaria</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Acessórios</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Alterações:

- Substitui:

  ```
  .menu ul li:hover ul{visibility: visible;}
  ```

  Com:

  ```
  .menu ul li:hover > ul{visibility: visible;}
  ```

  Essa regra quer dizer que quando o usuário der `:hover` em uma `li`, todos os `ul` que são filhos imediatos deste `li` vão ficar visíveis. Antes, o que estava acontecendo é que todos os `ul`, filhos ou netos, ou em qualquer nível dentro do `li:hover` estavam ficando visíveis, revelando todos os níveis ao mesmo tempo.
- Apaguei:

  ```
  menu ul ul li:hover ul{visibility: visible;}
  ```

  Essa regra ficou redundante com a anterior, pois aquela regra especifica qualquer `li:hover` com seu filho `ul` imediado.
- Adições ao final:

  Também adicionei mais alguns detalhes para fazer o terceiro nível aparecer do lado ao invés de abaixo:

  ```
  .menu ul li ul li { white-space: nowrap; }
  .menu ul li ul li > a { display: inline-block; width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box; }
  .menu ul li ul li > ul { display: inline-block; }
  ```

Note que sem essa última parte adicionada o CSS já ia funcionar, mas ia aparecer abaixo.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta Miguel. Deu certo.

Comment: Ok. Infelizmente, o CSS não disponibiliza uma forma de indicar todos os níveis pares ou impares. Sendo assim, se você quiser fazer um 4º nível, onde o menu sai pra baixo, terá de repetir regras, usando `ul > li > ul > li > ul > li` de nível em nível até chegar no item desejado. E pro 5º nível, o mesmo.

Answer (score 0):

eu fiz alguns ajustes no seu css: Informei que toda li que tiver uma ul e que esteja com o foco, eu torno o ul visível:

```
.menu ul li:hover > ul{visibility: visible;}
```

e para deixar alinhado eu vou na última ul e passo os seguintes valores e atributos:

```
.menu ul ul ul {position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 100%;}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Natan. Ficou quase bom. Quando o sub-item está na terceira linha. Mas quando está mais para baixo desalinha o texto. Estou editando a pergunta para anexar o resultado indesejado.